Standalone duende identityserver for multiple clients
Currently i'm setting up a project with an api and multiple clients that will connnect to this api (angular and .net maui). I want to use Duende identityserver for the authentication and autorization of this api and i was wondering if this is possible with a single identityserver project?
I've seen the solutions for angular frontend where the docs suggest using BFF and i've also seen examples where the identityserver has it's own frontend pages for the login process. While BFF would be sufficient for the angular app, it wouldn't be for the .net maui client. And the other way around, i cant use the generated frontend pages in the maui app.
Is there something i'm missing that would solve this issue of having multiple clients but wanting to centralize authentication? I cant imagine that other people with multiple frontend projects don't face similar issues and i'm curious how they solved this.

When working with OpenID Connect (IdentityServer) you always want to redirect and let the user enter his credentials in the UI provided by IdentitySever. That UI you can of course customize, but both your angular and MAUI app should both let the user login in the browser. Your users do not want to provide their username/pwd through your app. I also posted a OpenID Connect for Developers here  https://tn-data.se/openid-connect/
